# Passing an object from one android activity to another

Tags: android

I have a class that I'm using for parsing data from a csv file (called CSVReader), inside of that there is some methods for the parsing as well as a couple of strings and a list that is of a custom object type (List allRecords). 
What I'm doing is when the app loads, parsing all the data into that list and then trying to pass that information along to the next activity but inside the next activity I keep getting allRecords as being null.

LoginActivity

```
    CSVReader data = new CSVReader();
    data.populateRecords(this);
    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Find.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable("list", data);
    intent.putExtra("bundle", bundle);
    startActivity(intent);
```

I've gone through the debugger and the bundle definitely has the data in there.

Find

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("bundle");
data = (CSVReader) bundle.getParcelable("list");
```

Using the debugger still, and mMap (in the bundle) is now null and so is data.

Am I doing something wrong? Both classes DummyData and CSVReader implement Parcelable.

EDIT: Adding custom class CSVReader:

```
    List<DummyData> allRecords;
    private String base;
    private String location;
    private String partner;

    public static Creator<CSVReader> CREATOR = new Creator<CSVReader>(){
        @Override
        public CSVReader createFromParcel(Parcel source){
            return new CSVReader(source);
        }
        @Override
        public CSVReader[] newArray(int size) {
            return new CSVReader[size];
        }
    };

    private CSVReader(Parcel in){
            allRecords = new ArrayList<DummyData>();
            in.readTypedList(allRecords, DummyData.CREATOR);
            base = in.readString();
            location = in.readString();
            partner = in.readString();
    }
   ...
   ...

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeString(base);
            dest.writeString(location);
            dest.writeString(partner);
            dest.writeList(allRecords);
     }
```

Comment: Instead of `bundle.getParcelable("this");` it should be `bundle.getParcelable("list");`

Comment: @DanielZolnai you're right, but that didn't fix it either

Comment: please post your custom object class, the one you're trying to pass to the next activity.

Comment: @AndrewSenner posted the class

Comment: I've updated my answer, you need to read items from the parcel in the order they are written. I believe that is what is causing your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[EDIT]**

I was looking over your code again, and noticed you're writing the List to the parcel **LAST** and reading the list from the parcel **FIRST**. You have to read items from the parcel in the order they are written.  Try putting `dest.writeList(allRecords)` at the top of the method so it is the first item written, or you can put `in.readList(allRecords, DummyData.class.getClassLoader())` at the bottom of the list in that method.

Give it a shot.

//////////////////////////////////////////////

From the docs,

`public final void readTypedList (List<T> list, Creator<T> c)`

> Read into the given List items containing a particular object type
>   that were written with writeTypedList(List) at the current
>   dataPosition(). The list must have previously been written via
>   writeTypedList(List) with the same object type.

You're using `writeList()` to write the data to the parcel.  Try using `writeTypedList()`. You could also try changing `readTypedList()` with `readList()` I believe. Something like:

```
in.readList(allRecords, CSVReader.class.getClassLoader());
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh good point! I didn't even think of that messing things up but it makes sense that it would. I'll give it a shot and see what happens thanks

Comment: No problem :), happy to help.

Comment: @AndrewSenner That fixed it! Thanks again.

Comment: It's always a good feeling fixing a logical error, those things can be a pain in the butt! Good luck

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to pass data to another activity, you need to use objects of classes that implement Parcelable. Here is an example,

```
package com.weather.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class Forcast implements Parcelable {

private String id;
private String code;
private String message;
private City city;
private String count;
private List<Weather> weatherList = new ArrayList<Weather>();

public Forcast(){
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getCode() {
    return code;
}
public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}
public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}
public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
public City getCity() {
    return city;
}
public void setCity(City city) {
    this.city = city;
}
public String getCount() {
    return count;
}
public void setCount(String count) {
    this.count = count;
}
public List<Weather> getWeatherList() {
    return weatherList;
}
public void setWeatherList(List<Weather> weather) {
    this.weatherList = weather;
}


@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(id);
    dest.writeString(code);
    dest.writeString(message);
    dest.writeParcelable(city, flags);
    dest.writeString(count);
    dest.writeList(weatherList);

}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Forcast> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Forcast>() {

    @Override
    public Forcast createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new Forcast(source);
    }

    @Override
    public Forcast[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Forcast[size];
    }
};

protected Forcast(Parcel in){
    id = in.readString();
    code = in.readString();
    message = in.readString();
    city = (City)in.readParcelable(City.class.getClassLoader());
    count = in.readString();
    in.readList(weatherList, Weather.class.getClassLoader());
}

}
```

I included City model so you can see how it goes for an object in comparison to list of objects. Assume you have a Forcast instance with all the values as 'forcast' ( Forcast forcast = new Forcast() or something similar)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(com.weather.model,forcast)
startActivity(intent)
```

I hope that helps

Comment: My custom class looks pretty similar to that one, so I'm not sure why it isn't working. I did make some changes like changing `in.readTypedList(...)` to `in.readList(...)` but still not working. In your example how what would the `Weather` class look like?

Comment: you can see everything here. https://github.com/siambo/android/blob/master/WeazrAPI/src/com/weazrapi/model/Weather.java

Answer (score 0):

You need to put bundle object by using putExtras method. Then you can get the bundle by using getIntent().getExtras().

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Find.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelable("list", data);
intent.putExtras( bundle);
startActivity(intent);

Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
data = (CSVReader) bundle.getParcelable("list");
```